# Transfer Function Models :: Arimax in TSA

Tags: r, sas

I am trying to replicate the model from [forecasting with dynamic regression models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471615285) and I can't match the output in R using the arimax function from the TSA library. I am able to get pretty close to the result with SAS but I want to use R and hoping someone knows how to code the arimax function to achieve this. I have found the function to have issues (normally rooted from arima and optim) converging properly, but in this case a model is returned, but the parameters are way off.

The data is the first 140 observations from the sale sand lead series from Box and Jenkins in the `astsa` library.

Here is the snippet from the book showing their results (again, I could get close with SAS) and the code used with R (and the results). One thing I note is in the help file for arimax() there is recommendation to "mean-delete" transfer function covariates. I am not sure what this means and not sure if that is part of the issue.

From the book:

[image]

and here is the R-code:

```
library(TSA)
library(Hmisc)
library(astsa)


sales_140<-window(sales,end=140)
lead_140<-window(lead,end=140)

mod<-arimax(window(sales_140,start=4),order=c(0,1,1),
       xtransf = window(Lag(lead_140,3),start=4),transfer = list(c(1,0)),
       xreg=data.frame(seq(1:137)),method="ML")
mod


#Series: window(sales_140, start = 4) 
#ARIMA(0,1,1)                    

#Coefficients:
#         ma1  seq.1.137.  T1-AR1  T1-MA0
#      0.5974      0.3322  0.0613  2.8910
#s.e.  0.0593      0.1111  0.0275  0.1541

#sigma^2 estimated as 0.6503:  log likelihood=-163.94
#AIC=335.87   AICc=336.34   BIC=350.44
```

Here is the SAS code:

```
proc arima data=BL;
identify var=sales(1) crosscorr=lead(1);
estimate q=1 input=( 3 $ ( 0 ) / ( 1) lead) method=ml;
forecast out = out1 lead = 0;

run;
```

and the estimates:

[image]

Comment: Could you figure this out? I am working on something similar where I wanna do transfer function modeling with R but unable to understand usage of armiax function. Could you please share your findings on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ARIMAX models can be a bit difficult to implement/interpret in R. In this case there are a few things that tripped you up. Here they are in no particular order:

"mean-delete" is another way of saying "remove the mean". In this case, it refers to the covariate `lead_140`. So, start with

```
lead_140_Z <- lead_140 - mean(lead_140).
```

The order of the ARIMAX model you are trying to fit is (0,1,1), which is the same as ARMAX(0,1) on the first-differenced data. So, rather than work with the differencing inside of the model, just do so beforehand:

```
sales_140_D <- diff(sales_140)
lead_140_D <- diff(lead_140_Z)
```

In this case, the order of the transfer function is actually (1,3), but the first, second and third MA parameters (MA0, MA1 and MA2) are fixed at 0 (ie, only B^3 appears in the numerator). To address this, you need to use the `fixed` argument in `ARIMAX()` and specify `NA` for those params to estimate and `0` for those to omit.

You don't need anything for `xreg` as the covariate occurs in the transfer.

```
mod <- arimax(sales_140_D,
   order=c(0,0,1),
   include.mean=TRUE,
   fixed=c(NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA),
   xtransf=lead_140_D,
   transfer=list(c(1,3)),
   method="ML")

mod

# Coefficients:
          ma1  intercept  T1-AR1  T1-MA0  T1-MA1  T1-MA2  T1-MA3
      -0.5791     0.0286  0.7255       0       0       0  4.7092
s.e.   0.0756     0.0090  0.0040       0       0       0  0.0551
```

The results aren't exact, but they are quite close.